# How to concatenate 2 pytorch models and make the first one non-trainable in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I've two networks, which I need to concatenate for my full model. However my first model is pre-trained and I need to make it non-trainable when training the full model. How can I achieve this in PyTorch.

I am able to concatenate two models using [this answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/combining-trained-models-in-pytorch/28383/2?u=nagabhushansn95)

```
class MyModelA(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModelA, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10, 2)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x
    

class MyModelB(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModelB, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(20, 2)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x


class MyEnsemble(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, modelA, modelB):
        super(MyEnsemble, self).__init__()
        self.modelA = modelA
        self.modelB = modelB
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.modelA(x)
        x2 = self.modelB(x1)
        return x2

# Create models and load state_dicts    
modelA = MyModelA()
modelB = MyModelB()
# Load state dicts
modelA.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))

model = MyEnsemble(modelA, modelB)
x = torch.randn(1, 10)
output = model(x)
```

Basically here, I want to load pre-trained `modelA` and make it non-trainable when training the Ensemble model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can freeze all parameters of the model you dont want to train, by setting `requires_grad` to false.
Like this:

```py
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

This should work for you.

Another way is to handle this in your train-loop:

```py
modelA = MyModelA()
modelB = MyModelB()

criterionB = nn.MSELoss()
optimizerB = torch.optim.Adam(modelB.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for samples, targets in dataloader:
        optimizerB.zero_grad()

        x = modelA.train()(samples)
        predictions = modelB.train()(samples)
    
        loss = criterionB(predictions, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizerB.step()
```

So you pass the output of modelA to modelB but you optimize just modelB.

Comment: Why do you call `modelA.train()` if `modelA` is not being trained?

Comment: It looks like you do not use `x` after setting it. Nagabhushan rather wanted to use the output of `modelA` as input to `modelB`. You are feeding the same `samples` to both models, treating them independently, whereas Nagabhushan intended them to be sequential.

Answer (score 8):

One easy way to do that is to `detach` the output tensor of the model that you don't want to update and it will not backprop gradient to the connected model. In your case, you can simply `detach x2` tensor just before concatinating with `x1` in the forward function of `MyEnsemble` model to keep the weight of `modelB` unchanged.

So, the new forward function should be like following:

```
def forward(self, x1, x2):
        x1 = self.modelA(x1)
        x2 = self.modelB(x2)
        x = torch.cat((x1, x2.detach()), dim=1)  # Detaching x2, so modelB wont be updated
        x = self.classifier(F.relu(x))
        return x
```

Comment: Your solution is a bit different from what Nagabhushan asked, as he passes the output of `modelA` as input to `modelB`. Your solution takes separate inputs for both models. I am not sure if your solution would work in his case. Another thing: Nagabhushan wanted `modelA` to remain unchanged, while you, Kaushik, have done so for `modelB`. Since they should be sequential, with the output of `modelA` as input to `modelB`, this matters.